# Need a program to check all Ethernet ports in my office for it's proper functioning

Tags: ethernet

my office has a 20 Mbps leased line connection and we are using a firewall machine and unmanageable switches.
Now the problem is the we are getting a very slow speed on all the nodes and we are unable to find any broadcast storm using wire-shark.Now i am going through the lan ports one by one but i can check only the connectivity but not its health i mean how much is it performing. Is it up to the mark or has some other problem.
so i want a software (freeware i hope) which tells all about the connectivity of each port i plug into. Also any advise regarding the speed problem is welcome.

Comment: "unmanageable switches" :)  This is too vague for anyone to really help, but maybe with some more details: how many switches, how are they connected, how many workstations connected to them, etc.

Comment: there are 7 switches, all connected to each other by lan cables and we have about 50 w/s anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Nmap, there is a version for linux using command line and for windows with visual interface is called zenmap. You can specify an IP or a range, the port or a range of ports, even whole networks. But depending on the scan type, it can take some time to perform it.[Nmap website](https://nmap.org/)
You can also download a live version of kali linux to audit your network, but it will requiere further investigation, and nmap can do the job you need.

Comment: will try and report back

Comment: After reading again your question, you might refere to the phisical conections, instead of the range of ports that can be blocked by a firewall. If that is the case, you will need a network test device, I don't know any software that can replace this device.

Comment: OK that's what i was afraid of BTW do u know about such devices if only you could point me to a device available in Indian market

Comment: also nmap only told me about active/inactive ports.

Comment: KELUSHI Portable Multifunction Wireless Sc8108 LCD Digital PC Data Network CAT5 RJ45 LAN Phone Meter Length Cable Tester Meter
http://s.aliexpress.com/iU7BJJ7B
(from AliExpress Android) something similar to this I used during my networking lessons. You can check if there are problems with length and weak signal due to multiple switches